# I need some pointers on how to replicate this parallax animation?

Tags: jquery, css, parallax

The one I am referring to is found [over here](https://taplytics.com/), scroll down and you will see the phone elements roll out.

I see that the expanding div is just an image overlaid on a base image, and an animation occurs after scrolling down a certain amount.

Are there any tools that make these parallax animations easy to implement?

Comment: That thing is fun. Look at it with Firebug. It's a bunch of layers as background images and a few events.

Comment: Very neat usage. I wont submit an answer on this, but this seems like cleverly layered elements in which the elements are animating down leaving the highest indexed image not animating. jquery ui css animation would help. The pictures of the phone elements are already at an angle, so simply dropping the bottom images down would achieve this effect. Good luck. Looks cool.

Comment: I don't know if this will help but [this library](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: A library?  It's a couple of lines of code inside a scroll event handler.